# Android application which shows toast message when user turns on and off the Flashlight from the System

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, flashlight

I want to create an Android application using Java that displays the toast message when the user turns on or off the flashlight from the system and not from the app.
I discovered that there is no built-in broadcaster to receive this information and I have to create the custom broadcast receiver for this.
Please someone help with the logic to build the custom broadcast receiver for the state of the flashlight.

```
package com.example.lab7_torch;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TorchChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

        if(intent != null && intent.getAction() != null){
            if(intent.getAction().equals("android.hardware.action.Action_Torch_On")) {
                boolean isTorchOn = intent.getBooleanExtra("torch_state", false);

                if (isTorchOn){
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Torch is On", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Torch is Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        }

}
```

I tried this code for a custom broadcast receiver but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any broadcast receiver to register for tracking flashlight/torch status. Where do you get this `android.hardware.action.Action_Torch_On` from?

You would need to utilize the camera manager to track the status of the flashlight/torch.

ref: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager

you must also add Camera and Flashlight permissions to access the status.